# Trying to call stored proc using VB ASPX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, aspxgridview

I am trying to execute a stored procedure and place the data in a datagrid manually (without using the .net wizard). I am using vb.net and asp.net in visual studio.

Here is my code but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
Imports System.Data.Sql,
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic        
Partial Public Class WebForm3
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))

Public Cmd As New SqlCommand
Private _storedProc As String

Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString").ToString)

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim dt As SqlDataReader
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Cmd.CommandText = "proc_getTEST"
        Cmd.Connection = Conn

        Conn.Open()

        Try
            dt = Cmd.ExecuteReader
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            Conn.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a DataReader, you can use a SqlDataAdapter where you can set the SqlConnection and SqlCommand to execute then call the Fill method of the SqlDataAdapter passing the DataTable that want to fill.

Since your DataReader returns 2 result sets, you have to use a DataSet for this.  You will still use a SqlDataAdapter for this purpose but instead of passing a DataTable in the Fill method, you pass a DataSet and it will create 2 DataTables inside that DataSet.

Comment: so something like:     
  `Try
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found"
            GridView1.DataBind()
            Conn.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try`

Comment: Please try to comment the line "Conn.Dispose()" because DataReader
required continuous connection